# Sort rows in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sort rows in alphabetical order based on which column header is clicked using jQuery. It works fairly fine when debugging except that it doesn't actually switch the rows in the HTML and so it doesn't display a sorted table on the webpage. I'm using Thymeleaf th:text to populate the table body rows but for the sake of this example, I hardcoded some values. You can run it here: https://jsfiddle.net/tg2khrd4

### Javascript:

```
var table = $("#table");

$("#subject, #from, #id")
  .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
  .each(function () {
    var th = $(this),
      thIndex = th.index(),
      inverse = false;

    th.click(function () {
      table
        .find("tbody")
        .find("td")
        .filter(function () {
          return $(this).index() === thIndex;
        })
        .sort(
          function (a, b) {
            return $.text([a]) > $.text([b])
              ? inverse
                ? -1
                : 1
              : inverse
              ? 1
              : -1;
          },
          function () {
            // parentNode is the element we want to move
            return this.parentNode;
          }
        );

      inverse = !inverse;
    });
  });
```

### HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="table" style="background-color:#fff;border: 1px solid #cccccc">
  <thead style="background-color:#981e32;">
    <tr>
      <td class="tdsubj" id="id" style="padding:5px;">Id
      </td>
      <td class="tdsubj" id="subject" style="padding:5px;">
        Subject
      </td>
      <td class="tdsubj" id="from" style="padding:5px;">
        From
      </td>
      <td class="tdsubj" id="date" style="padding:5px;">
        Date
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Thor</td>
      <td>2020-10-19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Dinos Suck</td>
      <td>Meteor</td>
      <td>2020-9-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Big Ben won't stop ringing</td>
      <td>The Queen</td>
      <td>2020-8-19</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First, you have `var table = $("#table");` and `<table id="notice-table ..."` -- Then, i don't think jQuery `.each` takes two callbacks. The sorting seems to be working, but you do nothing with it.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette oops, sorry. I changed the id to make it easier but forgot to change it in the html. Fixed it in the edit. Thank you! :) Yes, I'm confused on how to use the sorted table rows to replace the existing rows since the sorted elements only consist of the specific column data and not the whole row, if that makes sense

Comment: @quantumPuter sorry. This is my first time posting about js. I added the jsfiddle

Comment: Did you forget to include jQuery?  Try this one.  https://jsfiddle.net/tg2khrd4/

Comment: @quantumPuter I remember including it. Idk what happened. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the `td` sorted... You just have to loop throught it and [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) it's parent `tr` in the table...

```js
var table = $("#table");

$("#subject, #from, #id")
  // .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
  .each(function () {
    var th = $(this),
      thIndex = th.index(),
      inverse = false;
      

    th.click(function () {
      let test = table
        .find("tbody")
        .find("td")
        .filter(function () {
          return $(this).index() === thIndex;
        })
        .sort(
          function (a, b) {
            return $.text([a]) > $.text([b])
              ? inverse
                ? -1
                : 1
              : inverse
              ? 1
              : -1;
          }

          // That is useless...
          /*function () {
                // parentNode is the element we want to move
                console.log(this.parentNode)
                return this.parentNode;
              }*/
        );

      // Added to demonstrate the sorting works
      console.clear()
      test.each(function () {
        console.log(this.innerText);
      });

      // Now to apply the sorting on the DOM
      // Find the tr containing it and append it to the table.
      test.each(function () {
        table.append($(this).parent("tr"))
      });

      inverse = !inverse;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="table" style="background-color:#fff;border: 1px solid #cccccc">
      <thead style="background-color:#981e32;">
        <tr>
          <td class="tdsubj" id="id" style="padding:5px;">Id
          </td>
          <td class="tdsubj" id="subject" style="padding:5px;">
            Subject
          </td>
          <td class="tdsubj" id="from" style="padding:5px;">
            From
          </td>
          <td class="tdsubj" id="date" style="padding:5px;">
            Date
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Hello</td>
          <td>Thor</td>
          <td>2020-10-19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Dinos Suck</td>
          <td>Meteor</td>
          <td>2020-9-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Big Ben won't stop ringing</td>
          <td>The Queen</td>
          <td>2020-8-19</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hahaha... I always do that reverse logic... I fixed my answer. ;)

Comment: haha guess it happens to the best of us too. It worked perfectly! Thank you so much! :)